# What is the purpose of the sentence "Absent default member initializers, ..." in the Note in [class.union]/3?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[class.union]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.union#3)

> A union can have member functions (including constructors and
>   destructors), but it shall not have virtual ([class.virtual])
>   functions. A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be
>   used as a base class. If a union contains a non-static data member of
>   reference type the program is ill-formed. [ Note: **Absent default
>   member initializers** ([class.mem]), if any non-static data member of
>   a union has a non-trivial default constructor ([class.default.ctor]),
>   copy constructor, move constructor ([class.copy.ctor]), copy
>   assignment operator, move assignment operator ([class.copy.assign]),
>   or destructor ([class.dtor]), the corresponding member function of the
>   union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted
>   ([dcl.fct.def.delete]) for the union. — end note ]

In the code below clang emits the same error message irrespective of whether the data member `U::i` has a default member initializer or not. See [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c1662e3a114226c).

```
#include <iostream>

struct S{
    int j = 1;
    S(const S&) {};
};

union U
{
    int i = 1;
    S s;
};

int main()
{
    U u;
}
```

Error message and note emitted by the compiler:

```
error: call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'U'  
U u;

note: default constructor of 'U' is implicitly deleted because field 's' has no default constructor
S s;
```

Comment: That seems like the expected behavior to me. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're parsing the sentence incorrectly. The *Absent default member initializers* clause is stating that a union member with a non-trivial default constructor can be initialized by a default member initializer instead of having to provide a default constructor for the union.

It's not saying that providing a default member initializer for a *different member* is sufficient to avoid the constructor requirement, which seems to be how you've read it.

The following example is valid because of the clause you highlight

```
struct S{
    int j = 1;
    S(int) {};
};

union U
{
    int i;
    S s = 1;
};

int main()
{
    U u;
}
```

Comment: Now I'm realizing that the words "non-trivial" in [class.union]/3 do not apply only to the default constructor, but also to the copy/move constructor, to the copy/move assignment operators and to the destructor. Is that correct? Look at [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41c171ec209bb045). The note issued by `clang` seems to confirm this.

Comment: @Belloc, that's correct, the sentence means for each special member function of a `union` member that is non-trivial, there must be a corresponding user provided version in the `union`, else it will be implicitly deleted.

Comment: @Praetorian I don't understand the reason why the default constructor for `U` is implicitly deleted. We have from [\[class.default.ctor\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#1) that `struct S` doesn't have a default constructor. But that doesn't allow us to conclude, from [class.union]/3, that the default constructor for the union `U` is implicitly deleted. I'm saying this in reference to the example given by @Belloc.